# A decorator to convert arguments of a function

Tags: python, decorator

I'd like to use a decorator to convert arguments of a function.

so instead of doing:

```
def get_data(dt, symbol, depth, session):
    dt = to_date(dt)
    ...
```

or

```
def get_data(dt, symbol, depth, session):
    dt = convert(dt, to_date)
    ...
```

I would like to be able to write something like

```
@convert('dt', to_date)
def get_data(dt, symbol, depth, session):
    ...
```

but I don't feel very confortable with this feature.

How to write such a decorator ?

Comment: Is there an actual question here? What problems did you face when you implemented the decorator?

Comment: I don't understand how to write this kind of decorator (because I have no experience with them)

Comment: what makes you think this would be a better way than how you are doing it? what exactly are you expecting that decorator to do ...

Comment: I think it will be much cleaner to ensure that each parameter which need to be converted are really converted. This kind of syntax looks nicer and is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Fiddled around with it a bit and learned quite a bit about generators:

```
def convert(arg, mod):
    def actual_convert(fn):
        if arg not in fn.__code__.co_varnames:
            return fn
        else:
            def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
                l_args = list(args)
                index = fn.__code__.co_varnames.index(arg)
                l_args[index] = mod(l_args[fn.__code__.co_varnames.index(arg)])
                args = tuple(l_args)
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            return new_function
    return actual_convert

@convert('x',lambda x: x+1)
def add(x,y):
    return x + y

print("Should be 5:",add(3,1))
```

This will only work with normal arguments for now, not keyword arguments. It would be fairly easy to do that, too, though.