# How can I type convert many arguments of a function in place?

Tags: python, function, type-conversion, cherrypy

### Context

I use [CherryPy](https://cherrypy.org/) to serve a simple webpage that shows different content based on the URL parameters. Specifically it takes the sum of the parameters and shows a different message based on that.
In CherryPy webpages can be defined as functions, and URL parameters are passed as an argument to that function.
As [explained in this tutorial](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-3-my-urls-have-parameters) URL parameters are passed as strings, so to calculate the sum I want to convert each argument to a float. I will have many URL parameters, so doing this one by one seems cumbersome.

**How can I type convert (a large number of) arguments in place?**

### What I've tried

#### Dumb

The "dumb" approach would be to simply take each argument and re-assign it as a float:

```py
def dumb(a="0", b="0", c="0", d="0", e="0", f="0", g="0"):
    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    c = float(c)
    d = float(d)
    e = float(e)
    f = float(f)
    g = float(g)

    return print(sum([a, b, c, d, e, f, g]))
```

It's readable, but rather repetitive and not very "pythonic".

#### Loop over `locals()`

Another option I found is to re-assign the locals to a dictionary, then loop over it and call the values from the dict.

```py
def looping_dict(a="0", b="0", c="0", d="0", e="0", f="0", g="0"):
    args = locals()
    for key in args:
        if key in ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]:
            args[key] = float(args[key])

    return print(sum([args["a"], args["b"], args["c"], args["d"], args["e"], args["f"], args["g"]] ) )
```

This is a bit annoying as I have to reference the dictionary every time. So a simple reference `d` becomes `args["d"]`. Doesn't help code readability neither.

Comment: Be aware that assignment to ``locals`` are implementation defined. There is no guarantee that they will work as expect, or keep on working as expected.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about cherrypy, or about Python in general? In the latter case, ``sum(map(float, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]))`` should do.

Comment: Well CherryPy is just the context to indicate why I can't simply pass float arguments to begin with. And I've simplified my examples to `sum`, in reality it's a custom function that calculates the average while discarding zero's. However I can try implementing the `map` suggestion in that function, thank you!

Comment: Oh, I just realised I use the arguments in other functions as well, and adding a float convert in every function would be cumbersome, so `map` is not a solution unfortunately (unless it can overwrite the original variable somehow).

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32774024/1256347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only documented in the changelog but since 2016 [with `cherrypy >= 6.2.0` there is a `@cherrypy.tools.params` tool](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/history.html#v6-2-0) doing exactly what you want (provided that you use a Python 3 version supporting type annotations):

```py
import cherrypy


@cherrypy.tools.params()
def your_http_handler(
        a: float = 0, b: float = 0,
        c: float = 0, d: float = 0,
        e: float = 0, f: float = 0,
        g: float = 0,
):
    return str(a + b + c + d + e + f + g)
```

The PR that added it is [PR #1442](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/pull/1442) — you can explore the usage by looking at the tests there.

If your Python is old for some reason, you could do:

```py
import cherrypy


def your_http_handler(**kwargs):
    # Validate that the right query args are present in the HTTP request:
    if kwargs.keys() ^ {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'}:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(400, message='Got invalid args!')

    numbers = (float(num) for num in kwargs.values())  # generator expression won't raise conversion errors here
    try:
        return str(sum(numbers))  # this will actually call those `float()` conversions so we need to catch a `ValueError`
    except ValueError as val_err:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(
            400,
            message='All args should be valid numbers: {exc!s}'.format(exc=val_err),
        )
```

P.S. In your initial post you use `return print(...)` which is wrong. `print()` always returns `None` so you'd be sending `"None"` back to the HTTP client while the argument of `print(arg)` would be just printed out in your terminal where you run the server.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion! That really looks perfect for my use case. 

P.S. I tried to make my question more general, hence I've focussed on type converting function arguments and didn't care of the effect on the HTTP client for the return `None` of `print()`.

Comment: Will do once I've tested it out at my job on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `@convert` decorator I've used before for something similar (originally inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268292/4597523):

```py
import functools, inspect

def convert(*to_convert, to):
    def actual_convert(fn):
        arg_names = inspect.signature(fn).parameters.keys()
        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            args_converted = [to(arg) if arg_name in to_convert else arg
                               for arg, arg_name in zip(args, arg_names)]
            kwargs_converted = {kw_name: to(val) if kw_name in to_convert else val
                                 for kw_name, val in kwargs.items()}
            return fn(*args_converted, **kwargs_converted)
        return wrapper
    return actual_convert

@convert('a', 'c', 'd', to=str)
def f(a, b, c=5, *, d, e=0):
    return a, b, c, d, e

print(f(1, 2, d=7))

# Output: ('1', 2, 5, '7', 0)
# Passed params `a` and `d` got changed to `str`,
# however `c` used the default value without conversion
```

It uses `inspect.signature` to get the non-keyword arg names. I am not sure how CherryPy passes the params or how it gets the names, but this might be a solid start. Using `functools.wraps` is important - it makes sure the original signature function signature is preserved, which seems to be important for CherryPy.

Comment: Could also use `**kwargs` syntax in the HTTP handler function to make it easier. But in general, I agree with the suggested solution. There are probably some schema libraries in the wild that could make things easier. Also, on newer Pythons you could inspect type annotations so it would be unnecessary to duplicate the schema...